# Courier IMAP, no response

Tags: ssl, imap, courier, courier-imap

I've got a Postfix with Courier IMAP mail server mostly set up. IMAP authentication works as expected on port 143 (when SSL is disabled), but whenever SSL is enabled or port 993 is used, nothing happens.

Literally, the server sends no data:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:993
```

> CONNECTED(00000003)
>   write:errno=104
>   ---
>   no peer certificate available
>   ---
>   No client certificate CA names sent
>   ---
>   SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 317 bytes
>   ---
>   New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
>   Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
>   Compression: NONE
>   Expansion: NONE
>   ---

I've made sure that `TLS_CERTFILE`, specified in `/etc/courier/imapd-ssl`, exists and is referenced correctly.

I've also made sure `IMAPDSSLSTART=1` and `IMAPDSTARTTLS=YES`.

I'm at a loss...

Comment: Try looking at your logs.

Comment: There don't appear to be any entries in mail.log from imapd-ssl at all

Comment: (nor in syslog)

Comment: Post all relevant configuration files and logs (yes, even if you don't spot anything there).

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, have you had any success?

Answer (score 0):

To properly test the `STARTTLS` feature, you need to use the following command:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:993 -startls imap
```

Without that `-starttls` option, you are not actually testing the encryption. From what info you have here it's wouldn't be clear whether you have a proper encryption setup.

OpenSSL can also be used to verify a specific version by adding an option such as `-tls1_2` to the command line. The connection will fail if the server doesn't support that specific version.